# Class 'AMQPConnection' not found; AMQP is installed, but not shown in phpinfo

Tags: php, apache, amqp

I am receiving the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'AMQPConnection' not found

I have installed it following `http://php.net/manual/fa/amqp.installation.php`

and:

```
extension=amqp.so
```

has been added to the main php.ini file and also the virtualhost's own.

and apache has been restarted.

On phpinfo, amqp appears under "Additional ini files parsed":

```
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/05-opcache.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-imap.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/25-amqp.ini
```

However the main amqp block which should appear under **Configuration doesn't exist.**

So it's almost like it's installed but not started / installed correctly.

When restarting apache it gives no errors.  So I am not sure where to look for any errors / reasons why it might not be starting or loading into phpinfo.

Comment: Just as a bit more info:

cat /proc/version ==> 
Linux version 3.13.0-29-generic (buildd@toyol) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014

and 

 pecl install amqp ==>pecl/amqp is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.4.0

Comment: Does php used as cgi or as apache module?

Comment: PHP is "FCGId (run as virtual server owner)"

Comment: Make sure proper php config loaded and amqp extension loaded itself, `phpinfo()` should show it in any cases.

Comment: I have ensured that the extension=amqp.so is in the right (loaded) php.ini. As explained, phpinfo() shows  it within additional files parsed, but that's it - it doesn't not show the full AMQP block under configuration. I have successfully passed messages between two terminals using Rabbit/AMQP so that works - it's just not loading for this specific VirtualHost it seems.

Comment: Ok, so can you try to use fresh amqp extension version (it probably require fresh librabbitmq too).

Comment: Thanks - I have tried installing a fresh amqp version inc a new and latest librabbitmq. Would there be any logs anywhere detailing any issues it has starting amqp?

Comment: in php startup logs or web server logs. Maybe extension can't load librabbitmq or something like that. I think this is very specific question and a bit offtopic question for SO, mostly because it is unclear how to reproduce your issue. It may sounds as "works for me", but it is not. Without clear steps to reproduce the issue it is unlikely to get help. And, btw, amqp-1.4.0 is totally outdated, use 1.6.0 latest beta, it is stable enough, we just have few changes we want to add to release and we don't want to increase version number for nothing.

Comment: Thanks for comments so far. Did a complete new install of librabbit and amqp and the install processes all went smoothly with no errors. Upon restart of apache however, log returns this warning: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/amqp.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/amqp.so: undefined symbol: amqp_empty_table in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Just look over the issue (probably, closed one) on github page https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp, we had something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I cleared out all the librabbit files that find -iname "*rabbit*" could find in /usr.

Reinstalled rabbitmq-c and amqp v 1.6 beta 3

Then received the error in apacge start up logs:

`PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/amqp.so' - librabbitmq.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

So it seemingly couldn't find librabbit.so.4 so I created a symlink to where it was looking, restarted apache and the issue is resolved.

Thanks